# What's wrong with this recursive curried function

Tags: function, recursion, f#, currying

I was trying to write a function that solves following;

```
persistence 39 = 3  // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                    // and 4 has only one digit

persistence 999 = 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                    // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

persistence 4 = 0   // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

After I solved the question I tried to make all functions looks like Ramda.js function styles like this;
This code works;

```
let multiply = List.reduce (*)

let gt from input = input > from

let just input = fun _ -> input

let ifElse cond trueFn falseFn input =
  if cond input then trueFn input else falseFn input

let digits n =
  (string n) |> Seq.toList |> List.map (System.Char.GetNumericValue >> int)
  
let rec persRec iter current =
  current 
  |> digits 
  |> multiply
  |> ifElse (gt 9) (persRec (iter + 1)) (just iter)

let persistence n = if n > 9 then persRec 1 n else 0
```

But when I tried to modify persRec function with a curried composed version like following, it makes this stack overflow.

```
let rec persRec iter = 
  digits 
  >> multiply
  >> ifElse (gt 9) (persRec (iter + 1)) (just iter)
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `persRec` is calling itself unconditionally. Here:

```
>> ifElse (gt 9) (persRec (iter + 1)) (just iter)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                           |
                           unconditional recursive call
```

This happens always. Every time `persRec` is called by somebody, it immediately calls itself right away.

You may expect that the recursive call should only happen when `gt 9`, because, after all, it's inside an `ifElse`, right? But that doesn't matter: `ifElse` is not special, it's just a function. In order to call a function, F# has to compute all its parameter *before* the call (aka "applicative order of evaluation"), which means it has to call `persRec (iter + 1)` before it can call `ifElse`, and it has to call `ifElse` before it can call `(>>)`, and it has to call `(>>)` in order to compute result of `persRec`. So ultimately, it needs to call `persRec` in order to compute the result of `persRec`. See where this is going?

The previous version works, because the body of `persRec` is not actually executed before the call to `ifElse`. The body of `persRec` will only be executed when all its parameters are supplied, and the last parameter will only be supplied inside the body of `ifElse` when the condition is true.

---

The way I see it, the confusion stems from the difference between denotational and operational semantics. Yes, mathematically, logically, the functions are equivalent. But execution also matters. Normal vs. applicative evaluation order. Memory concerns. Performance. Those are all outside of the domain of lambda-calculus.

Comment: (persRec iter) returns a function and its pure. So from a perspective of Haskell world I would expect it to be cached and dont call itself again and again (if you are working with curried functions). Or maybe I could make it lazy so it would be sitting and waiting there for me to call it with full parameters. Is there any way to do that in F#? I couldn't make f#'s Lazy work for my example.

Comment: Haskell uses _normal_ evaluation order, which means function body doesn't get executed until the function result is required. F# uses _applicative_ evaluation order (as do most other languages), which means that function body is executed as soon as all formal parameters are provided. `persRec` has only one formal parameter - `iter`, - so its would get executed as soon as `iter` is provided. It doesn't matter what the result type is - function or not, - the function body is executed as soon as all parameters are provided. Period.